# Converting double array to IComparable array

Tags: .net, vb.net, icomparable

I'm trying to create a Quicksort base class using VB.NET, taking it an array of IComparable elements.  The signature looks like this:

```
public shared sub Sort(ByVal values() as IComparable)
```

However, when I pass in an array of doubles, the compiler is giving me errors.

```
Dim numbers(100) as double
Dim random as new Random(0)
for i as integer = 0 to numbers.length - 1
  numbers(i) = random.NextDouble()
Next

QuickSort.Sort(numbers) ' gives compiler error.
```

The error is:

```
Error   88  Value of type '1-dimensional array of Double' cannot be converted to '1-dimensional array of System.IComparable' because 'Double' is not derived from 'System.IComparable'. C:\Proving Grounds\Module1.vb
```

The .NET documentation states that double's implement IComparable.  Why isn't the .NET compiler letting me do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although `double` can be cast to `IComparable`, it doesn't mean that `double[]` can be cast to `IComparable[]`. A simple option would be to create a new `IComparable[]` array and copy the data over - or in your case, simply start the original array as `IComparable[]`.

Actually, I'd be tempted to use the generic `IComparable<T>` or `IComparer<T>` interfaces, or the `Comparison<T>` delegate - all using generics - this also allows use of `Comparer<T>.Default` and non-default comparers.

Comment: Oh, right.  I should actually USE those new language features.

Comment: Can you give an example how to write the sort method with generics ?

Comment: @Alex need more context - what is the input? But one of: IComparable-of-T, IComparer-of-T or Comparer-of-T.Default